# Odd SQL connection error received when under high load

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

I can connect to my MSSQL 2017 database via JDBC just fine, however when the database server is under heavy load, I get this connection error when running a query.

Have I simply maxed out what the server can do? 
Maybe this is a NIC related issue?
Any performance settings adjustments to make?

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
The TCP/IP connection to the host 192.168.1.150, port 1433 has failed. 
Error: "Connection timed out: no further information. 
Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of 
SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections 
at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Server have problems when are too many connections and worker threads from clients.

You can check current count of connections.

```
Select Count(*) FROM MASTER.DBO.SYSPROCESSES
```

There are dependencies between CPU cores and worker threads. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017

Max worker threads on your host.

```
Select max_workers_count from sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

Also you can see wait types THREADPOOL in TOP.

```
SELECT TOP 100
 [Wait type] = wait_type,
 [Wait time (s)] = wait_time_ms / 1000,
 [% waiting] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2), wait_time_ms * 100.0 
               / SUM(wait_time_ms) OVER())
FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
WHERE wait_type NOT LIKE '%SLEEP%' 
ORDER BY wait_time_ms DESC;
```

About waits threadpool:
https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/threadpool/

Check this version.

Or I don't understand situation and you have problem after X seconds after connection and work query. 
Check query timeout in your application via the connection string something like "queryTimeout=..."

Comment: any idea why the database would not just queue the request, instead of rejecting the connection?